# Drug-DNA complex simulation using AMBER

Tags: ngs, phylogenetics, docking, drugs, molecular-dynamics

I want to carry out the simulation of drug-dna complex by placing the drug molecule at particular site in my DNA sequence (intercalating site). I have PDB files of both drug and DNA sequence. I will truly appreciate if anyone could guide me how to place my drug at the desired location in the DNA sequence using Amber.

Comment: If it is only one... Can you not place it by dragging it in PyMOL?
Also do check out this discussion thread about the issue of aromatic dipole moments and forcefields: https://www.researchgate.net/post/Pi-pi-and-cation-pi-interactions-in-force-fields

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I can try that. However, I want to know how can I know  different base pairs in pymol. When I load the pdb file of my DNA sequence the base pairs cartoon all look same. Do you have any recommendations for teh software I can use to load my DNA and ligand pdb file and insert it into specific sequence and then save file as pdb  may be.

Comment: PyMOL shows everything as cartoon by default, but you can show them as licorice. Say `show sticks, polymer.nucleic`. There are a few other representations possible —cf. right hand side panel under (S) for show.

Comment: I should mention, to drag stuff, click on 3-button viewing on the right hand side panel making "editing", shift+wheel button ought to be Move object. Make sure to save often as there's no undo!

Comment: Thank you for your help